# Keep altas robot from falling while turning in place

Tags: python, gazebo-1.7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've designed a python script that will allow the atlas robot in the drc simulator to walk by keyboard input.

However there is a flaw in turning on a point (input z/c), whenever it finishes it ends up leaning back and collapsing.

Any ideas on how to correct this? My first though is to lean forward, but I have no idea how to do that. The script is attached below to test.

[qt1.py](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13831022845938539.py)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4860/keep-altas-robot-from-falling-while-turning-in-place/) by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 34 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This [script](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/1f290ef5f80b365da499ef1ec62e110dbd616d0e/drcsim_gazebo/scripts/qual_1_bridge.py?at=default) creates a set of steps for Atlas to follow. Maybe it can help you.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0